# Podcast byte-range requests

Tags: lamp

### Background

Apple podcasts must be served from a byte-range enabled server.  This allows users to stream episodes.  More info here:  http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html.

I have Lamp stack Apache/PHP/Mysql.  When I test with wget or Curl (specifying byte-range) and request static files from the server byte-range works - Apache is doing its thing.

When I request dynamic content the request is handed to PHP, which then hands the entire file to Apache, which then completes the request delivering the entire file.  THis is expected behaviour.

### Question

I was curios to what others have implemented to get round this.

At first I considered Apache rewrites to point to the physical file on the server.  However due to some app requirements this is not possible in this situation.

Placing Nginx at the top of the stack and configuring it to handle byte-range requests. Nginx > Apache > PHP.

Updating the PHP code to handle byte range requests.

Thanks for reading.  I'm interested to the best way to resolve this.

THanks again.

Comment: just run test with x-sendfile and seems like a reasonable solution to this.